# Axios does not return the error in the frontend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, mern

I create a server on NodeJs by using Express and MongoDB (Mongoose) to create REST API after that I connect that API to my Frontend (ReactJS). the problem is that when I send post request from Axios, but on error (Duplicate Key) they not respond to catch and give a response on .then like that `{data: "You Cannot Add Duplicate Link", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}`

FrontEnd:

```
axios
  .post(`${SERVER}`, post) // Here Post is an object
  .then(async res => {
    await this.setState({ host: res.data._id });
  })
  .then(() => this.setState({ loading: false }))
  .catch(async error => {
    await this.setState({ error: error.res });
  });
}
```

BackEnd:

```
const post_link_with_id = async (req, res) => {
  await models
   .create({
     // Objects like obj_key: req.body.obj_model
    })
   .then(result => res.send(result))
   .catch(err =>
      err.code === 11000 ? res.send("You Cannot Add Duplicate Link") : ""
    );
 };
```

Comment: `this.setState` is async, but does not return a Promise. Also, you could set all state properties in one `setState` call instead of chaining `.then` like that.

Comment: Keep in mind that setState() does not return a promise, doing await this.setState() will not do anything, especially will not synchronously wait for setState() to complete.

Comment: It's also discouraged to mix `async/await` and `.then/catch`. Choose one or the other, but stick with it.

Comment: thanks for extra advice I will keep in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are sending `error status` while send the response from the server.

The standard way to send a response is by using a status code.

Like,

```
res.status(statusCode).send(responseMessage);
```

For error in server, you should use the following response,

```
err.code === 11000 ? res.status(404).send("You Cannot Add Duplicate Link") : "";
```

Your final backend code should,

```
const post_link_with_id = async (req, res) => {
  await models
   .create({
     // Objects like obj_key: req.body.obj_model
    })
   .then(result => res.send(result))
   .catch(err =>
      err.code === 11000 ? res.status(400).send("You Cannot Add Duplicate Link") : ""
    );
 };
```

You may want to change the suitable status code.

For details, check the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html).

Also fix your front end `setState()` method, as suggested in the comments.